CSS Zoom Property alters event coordinates, need workaround
First of
I work on a html/js/css module injected in third party page which is autoscaled using CSS zoom. I cannot remove the zoom property from the parent element as it is automatically added using some polling mechanism. I have NO access to the code and the customer will NOT change it.
Problem
My own embedded code is basically another third party library, lets call it THS. The THS library does  make use of event.pageX and event.pageY values in its event handlers. Since the whole code is wrapped in an element using zoom the event coordinates are not correct anymore. So I have clicks and hovers on wrong positions.
Showcase
I can only edit html code within the div#custom-container element. The div#main-container is the element which gets zoom automatically applied.


const mainContainer = document.getElementById('main-container')

// enable / disable zoom
const zoomCb = document.getElementById('zoom-enabled')
zoomCb.addEventListener('click', () => {
    mainContainer.style.zoom = zoomCb.checked ? '50%' : ''
})

const workspace = document.getElementById('custom-container')

// Sample pageX and pageY are wrong when using zoom
workspace.addEventListener('click', e => {
    const point = document.getElementById('point')
    point.style.left = e.pageX + 'px'
    point.style.top = e.pageY + 'px'
})
#point {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: red;
    height: 25px;
    width: 25px;
}

#main-container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 300px;
}

#custom-container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}


   
 <p>Click somewhere to move the red square</p>
  <label>
    enable zoom
    <input type="checkbox" id="zoom-enabled">
</label>


<div id="main-container">
    <div id="custom-container">
        <div id="point"></div>
    </div>

</div>



When zoom is disabled the #point div element is moved to correct place. With enabled zoom it is not.. I read in the documentation that the boundaries of the elements is changed when using css zoom and that's why these coordinates are wrong, but again, I cannot remove the zoom property.
What I tried / found
CSS transform can replace zoom fully wihtout changing element boundaries. So click events provide propper coordinates.
So I tried to reset the zoom in the root of my custom module and apply transform accordingly. But Setting zoom: reset has no effect on my elements, the reset value is not regonised in most recent versions of firefox/chrome/edge ...
I have no clue what I could try instead of rewriting like all the THS modules code but that will cost me weeks plus bringing the changes to the third party hoster etc.
last

If anything is unclear, let me know.
The code snippet showcases my problem and is only sandbox reproduction.
Again, zoom is unavoidable in my scenario. Answers pointing out I should NOT use zoom do not help at all.
Any other ideas are appreciated.

TY for reading, I value your time!>
Edit1
The answer of @Tom4nt does not help me since The code which reads event.pageY resp. event.pageY is out of my reach.

Can you detect the zoom level of the embedding page, from within your own code? At least in Chrome, dividing the X/Y value by that zoom factor, appears to make it work fine. (Zoom factor 50% -> e.pageX / .5 + 'px', zoom factor 33% -> e.pageX / .333 + 'px', and the same for Y of course.)

The explanation of how the use of CSS transform fails is a bit messy ... Can't you just set transform: scale(1, 1); when resetting the scaling?

What comes to "zoom is unavoidable", it's really a bad idea to rely on non-standard features, they tend to stop working in the future, and then you'll be in the troubles again.

@Teemu
I simply have no impact on the code which introduces the zoom. That is it. It is a bad idea to use zoom but I can do nothing.

@Cbroe
Yes I can get the zoom factor. I can retrieve the zoomed Container element, and read the CSS rule itself.

@Teemu
I will also adjust the transform explanation and play a lil more with it.

If the script part that reads pageX/Y is out of your reach, you can also apply the "reverse" zoom to #custom-container.

There's already an answer for the original question. Please make your edits so, that they won't invalidize the existing answer. If you want to make your code to work with transform, it would be OK to ask a totally new question. In that question, also explain how the third-party library is involved in the issue.

@Cbroe
With reverse Zoom I could successfully "remove" the zoom. That is surely a step in the correct direction.

@Teemu
Since a comment answered the main part of the question I will add a short answer pointing that out. I come up with new and more specific questions if other  blocking problems arrive.
Thanks guys, appreciate it.

Thanks to a comment of @Cbroe it is possible to apply the reverse zoom to my custom container to mitigate the zoom effect.


//calculate reverse zoom factor of css zoom rule value
function reverseZoom(factorStr) {
    const factor = parseFloat(factorStr)

    // Allow units in factorStr like percentage
    const unit = factorStr.replace((''+factor), '')
    const reverse = 100 / factor
    return (100 * reverse) + unit
} 

const mainContainer = document.getElementById('main-container')
const workspace = document.getElementById('custom-container')

// enable / disable zoom
const zoomCb = document.getElementById('zoom-enabled')
zoomCb.addEventListener('click', () => {

    var zoomFactor = ''
    var reverseFactor = ''

    if(zoomCb.checked) {
        zoomFactor = '50%'
        reverseFactor = reverseZoom(zoomFactor)
    }

    mainContainer.style.zoom = zoomFactor
    workspace.style.zoom = reverseFactor
})


// Sample pageX and pageY are wrong when using zoom
workspace.addEventListener('click', e => {
    const point = document.getElementById('point')
    point.style.left = e.pageX + 'px'
    point.style.top = e.pageY + 'px'
})
#point {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: red;
    height: 25px;
    width: 25px;
}

#main-container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 300px;
}

#custom-container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}


   
 <p>Click somewhere to move the red square</p>
  <label>
    enable zoom
    <input type="checkbox" id="zoom-enabled">
</label>


<div id="main-container">
    <div id="custom-container">
        <div id="point"></div>
    </div>

</div>



With zoom removed it is now possible to apply transform css property to make container still fit in size but allow correct click coordinates. I do not cover the follow up step here.

Try dividing the coordinates by the current zoom level.


const mainContainer = document.getElementById('main-container')

// enable / disable zoom
const zoomCb = document.getElementById('zoom-enabled')
zoomCb.addEventListener('click', () => {
    mainContainer.style.zoom = zoomCb.checked ? '50%' : ''
})

const workspace = document.getElementById('custom-container')

// Sample pageX and pageY are wrong when using zoom
workspace.addEventListener('click', e => {
    const zoomLevel = getComputedStyle(mainContainer).zoom

    const point = document.getElementById('point')
    point.style.left = e.pageX / zoomLevel + 'px'
    point.style.top = e.pageY / zoomLevel + 'px'
})
#point {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: red;
    height: 25px;
    width: 25px;
}

#main-container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 300px;
}

#custom-container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}


   
 <p>Click somewhere to move the red square</p>
  <label>
    enable zoom
    <input type="checkbox" id="zoom-enabled">
</label>


<div id="main-container">
    <div id="custom-container">
        <div id="point"></div>
    </div>

</div>




Thanks for the answer!. The zoom is applied correctly. But the code to adjust it is also out of my reach. So this does not solve my problem
